Definition of Hilbert schemes - $\mathbb{P}_S^n$
I am trying to fully understand the notion of Hilbert schemes. My point of confusion right now is notation $\mathbb{P}_S^n$ used by
Stein Arild Stromme "Elementary Introduction to Representable Functors and Hilbert Schemes", Parameter Spaces, Banach Center Publications, 36, Institute of Mathematics, Polish Academy of Sciences, 179-198,1996.
He uses the notation $\mathbb{P}_{k}$ to denote the projective space with respect to field $k$, and $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ to denote $n$-dimensional projective space over field $k$. That is clear. But now, on page 187 (page 9), he drops the notation $\mathbb{P}_S^n$ for a scheme $S$. He does define $\mathbb{P}(V)$ but for a vector space $V$, and scheme is not a vector space. Any help on what does he mean?

$\mathbb{P}^n_S = \mathbb{P}^n_{ \mathbb{Z}} \times_{\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}} S $

I found it in Hartshorne, now I feel stupid, but thankies!!!
